# Is it better to create one label and update its text from code-behind, or create multiple labels and show/hide the label as needed?

Tags: asp.net, .net, label

Repeating question: Is it better to create one label and update its text from code-behind, or create multiple labels and show/hide the label as needed?

**Case: one label, update from code-behind**

- There is only one label created on the aspx page, which keeps the page light-weight.
- The code remains clean on .aspx page, as well as the code-behind page.
- Chances of wrong or multiple text/ labels displaying is minimized.

**Case: multiple labels with texts, show/hide label from code-behind**

- All the possible texts is already visible from the .aspx page; updating does not require re-compiling.

I see merits and demerits in both approaches. I just can not decide on which approach to take. Perhaps, it depends upon how many different possible texts choices there are, but what is a good general rule of thumb?

Comment: Do whatever increases readability, don't care about performance(theres practically no difference since controls that are `Visible=false` won't be rendered at all). Use one label for one subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking about this from a maintenance point of view. If you had quite a few labels on the screen and were hiding/showing them then the code would be quite messy and I would want to kill you. Also remember that ASP.Net webforms has to pump all the server side controls' state in the form of viewstate. More viewstate means slower pages.

Comment: _"More viewstate means slower pages."_ Can you explain this in more detail? Your point is not really clear.

Comment: ASP.Net uses ViewState to remember what the state of your controls were on each page in between interactions with server controls. Remember the web is stateless. There is no way to remember what the text of a button was when posting back to the same page. The webserver is responding to a request. There is no way to access the memory that holds the text value of the button because there is none. Webforms tries to give this to you by sending the state of all server controls to the page in encrypted region called viewstate. When you post back to the same page the view state gets posted too so...

Comment: webforms can figure out what the state was and recreate it in memory for you. More server side controls = more viewstate that must be sent back and forth.

Comment: ViewState will only be sent when it was changed(when it differs from its initial state).

Comment: @Tim - What do you mean when say "differs from its initial state". Do you mean default or the state that it was in when the page was rendered. I can understand them being able to save on default data not being sent because they can assume default if not preset. But how does ASP.Net keep track of the initial values then. Are you sure it doesn't send the whole lot up again?

Comment: Basically a control does only store properties in ViewState which have changed during the page's life-cycle(since `TrackViewState`). A control which state was changed is "dirty". For example if you  change `TextBox1.Text` in page_load, `ViewState.IsItemDirty("TextBox1.Text")` would return `true`. These values will be stored in ViewState. See [**here**](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) and [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). (I really recommend to read both articles)

Comment: The initial values and the control hierarchy(even html-controls) are compiled into Temporary ASP.NET Files when the page is first requested.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for one control.

Tim -> When visible set to false controls won't be rendered, but they will be initialized on server side. So there is some difference.

Comment: I guess the answer, at the end, will boil down to: it depends. E.g. if I do not care about the server resource, but am constantly changing the requirements for the texts, it would be ok to create multiple labels. On the other hand, I could always create one label and pull the texts from the web.config for updates w/o compiling. At this point, I am leaning towards one label. @Tim This increases readability as well and is good for maintenance.